# Magento 2 login page broken

Tags: magento2

So all pages are working fine but except this page https://softncozy.com/customer/account/login is not loading the contents properly, after spending some time i found out that all the urls are missing "pub/static" from the base url while all other pages on the website works fine. 
I'm very new to magento, so I'm not sure what's happening here.

Edit 1: Everything works fine if i set Use Web Server Rewrites to NO ... but it adds index.php on every single page

Comment: Please run ```php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US```

Comment: And any other locale you may applied to your config

Comment: @pontikos looks like first i'll have to make it production

Comment: @pontikos so ran that code and website is not even opening now

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are in production mode on the server, but you can check that with magento console command, go to Magento root folder and run:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

if you are in production mode then run:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

After executing of this two commands, all need it files will be generated.

Comment: its in development mode but i tried to make it production and it gave me error **Command returned non-zero exit code:
`/usr/bin/php7.2 -f /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:di:compile`**

Comment: to make in production use this command `bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/2C43fDh.png yes i tried, something's wrong

Comment: First, try to avoid using **sudo**. Please check the error log, to find any evidence why compile is failing.

Comment: hey i found something, if i put domain/index.php/.... in the url, it works! still not sure why

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed and you should follow the below stepd to fix it.

1) remove var/, generated and pub/static/frontend & pub/static/adminhtml.
From the Magento root folder please run below command. (if required you can disable merge and minify CSS and JS from the backend)

> rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*
>   var/report/* var/log/* generated/* pub/static/frontend/* &
>   pub/static/adminhtml/*

2) Currently, you are in developer mode, so I would suggest first fix this issue in developer mode then after you can go with production.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento
>   setup:static-content:deploy -f

3) Once done above command, please provide proper permission for var/ pub/ and generated folder.

If the issue is fixed then you can change mode and see if you are getting this issue again or not.

Last thing you can try if you are still facing any issue then try with disable custom modules & custom theme and try.

Hope this will help you.

Please let me know if you still facing this issue.

Comment: sounds like alot of critical work, i dont want to risk losing any data... may be i should hire someone experienced

Comment: Please email me, I will help you with this. nitish250788@gmail.com